# How to update individual values of the box-shadow property?

Tags: css

I'd like to override the distance on `box-shadow` without having to set the color again.

Use case here is I have a `.button` class with this:

```css
.button {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 black;
}
```

Then I have a `.button-small` class that is effectively a child of `.button` that makes some minor tweaks to things.

```css
.button.button-small {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 black;
}
```

As you can see, I can easily change the `border-width` without redefining the entire `border` property.

Is there a way to do that with `box-shadow`? Some sort of `box-shadow-distance` property?

Comment: No, sadly there is no way to adjust only the offset of the shadow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS variables:

```css
.button {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 var(--d, 5px) 0 black; /* 5px is the fallback/default value until you set the variable */
}

.button.button-small {
  --d: 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="button">button</span>

<span class="button button-small">button</span>

<span class="button" style="--d:8px;">button</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Unlike other properties, such as border, in which the parts are broken up into sub-properties, the box-shadow property stands alone. This means that it is even more important to take note of the order in which the parts are stated, particularly the length values. [The box-shadow Property](https://bitsofco.de/the-box-shadow-property/)